# Matrix Algebra: finding what values of a does system have nontrivial solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Instructions are to: find what values of 'a' does system have nontrivial solutions

The original equations are

\begin{equation}
    x+2y+z=0
    \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-x-y+z=0
 \end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    3x+4y+(a)z=0
 \end{equation}

I tried to simplify it to

$[1 $ $ 2$ $  1  |$ $  0  ]$

$[0 $ $ 1  $ $2  |  $ $0  ]$

$[0 $ $ 0 $ $ (4+a)  |$ $  0  ]$

but was not sure where to go from here, book didn't help too much, what should my next approach be?

Comment: Sorry, forgot it, I edited it in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your system is given by $A\vec x=\vec 0$ where
$$
A=
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 2 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & 1 \\
3 & 4 & a
\end{array}\right]
$$
Note that this system has non-trivial solutions if and only if $\det A=0$. But
$$
\det A=a+1
$$
Hence the system has non-trivial solutions if and only if $a=-1$.

Comment: You mean $\det =0$?

Comment: yes. edited....